# Passing canvas.toDataURL() to ffmpeg.wasm issues

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to setup canvas animation convertion to video with FFMPEG.wasm. The idea is to generate a bunch of images with `canvas.toDataURL()` then send them to a Node server to generate a video. Everything works perfectly with preuploaded images I am pulling from the public directory for testing, however when I try to send a bunch (or a single) of images created with `canvas.toDataURL()` I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: abort(Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open 'data:image/png;base64, ...
```

I tried to replace `canvas.toDataURL()` with `canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData()`, however this didn't help either. Below is a cut code I am using:

front:

```
async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/record-canvas', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ image: here_goes_the_canvas_data }),
  });
}
```

backend:

```
await ffmpeg.load();
ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', `001.png`, await fetchFile(image));
await ffmpeg.run('-loop', '1', '-i', '001.png', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-t', '30', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 'out.mp4');
await fs.promises.writeFile('out.mp4', ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'out.mp4'));
```

The code above is simplified to make a video of a single image looping it for 30 seconds. Again, works great with preuploaded image, however not with the canvas data.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came across the same issue, this is the solution I came up with :

1. `dataURL` must be `jpeg` (eg. `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')`).
2. You need to transform it into a Buffer value (e.g.  `Buffer.from(image.split(',')[1], 'base64')` before passing to FFMPEG's `fetchFile` function.

Comment: Can you share a simple example of capturing a canvas in a loop and outputting an mp4 using ffmpeg.wasm through a serverless application please?

Comment: @Curious, I failed to make it work with ffmpeg.wasm in the end. It doesn't work on the front-end too. Went with fluent-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-static and Firebase Functions which worked just fine.

Comment: So you managed to use ffmpeg-static in the front end to create an exportable mp4 from Canvas elements added one by one as frames?

Comment: You can convert a canvas animation into a bunch of images on the front-end, however ffmpeg doesn't work on the front-end (even though guys from ffmpeg.wasm claim it does, I think it only works in Firefox if I am not mistaken). So you need some server to actually assemble those images into a video file. I went with Node.js and Firebase Functions. So the steps are 1) generate a bunch of images on the front-end 2) upload those images somewhere 3) create a custom Firebase function to pull those images from your storage and assemble them into a video file, add music and other fancy things you need

Comment: Theres got to be a client side way of handling this.